# What am I typing wrong in this simple PHP Twig program?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

What am I typing wrong here? I want to print out a string that says "LarryMoeCurly"

I assume that if I feed an array to the template engine it can access it in the 'users' loop.

-- CODE

```
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('gen_form.html');
  $users = array("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
  echo $template->render($users);
```

-- TEMPLATE (gen_form.html)

```
  {% for user in users %}
     {{ user }}
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
echo $template->render(array('users' => $users));
```

In your case $users - it is just a name of your variable containing array like ["Larry", "Moe", "Curly"]. So there is no key 'users' in it.

Comment: Why should they? Explain what's going on here!

Comment: You pass in an array that is a key/value pair so in your twig template the keys become the variables. `'users' => $users` makes a variable `users` that has the value of the corresponding key/value pair (your users array). With your array of `"Larry", "Moe", "Curly"` you are actually passing in an the key/value pairs of `0 => Larry`, `1 => Moe` and `3 => Curly` with the only reference to `users` being your original variable name which is not taken into consideration.